# Having issues displaying forms in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating a project using Windows Forms on the .NET framework.
It's created and everything looks fine.

But when I close and reopen the project, the form designer is gone (`form.cs` and `form.Designer.cs` are still there but the actual form template is gone).

Can someone help?

i have uploaded a picture for better understanding.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCXRm.png)

Comment: nope it shows nothing.@jdweng

Comment: Try right click of parent.  The form should open the same was the cs source code opens.  Is there a resx file in the project folder?

Comment: I'm sure I saw someone else asking the same recently.. Is your project a net framework or a net core(5+) one?

Comment: yeah i saw this option but i specifically focused on picking the .net framework @CaiusJard

Comment: i have included a pic in the post @jdweng

Comment: You're in folder view. You need to actually open the solution. Double click on the .sln file.

Comment: oh don't mind me i just clicked on sem7 project .sln and it seems fine. excuse my ignorance i'm new to visual studio .

Comment: Next time, just open the solution file directly from Windows File Explorer or in VS via File > Open > Project/Solution, then you won't have to waste time in folder view.

Comment: You are missing the resx file.  Try creating a new project and you should see the resx.

Comment: @jdweng That wasn't the issue. Look at Charbel's most recent comment. They just needed to actually open the solution.

Comment: thank you all. i know i have  wasted your time so pardon me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in folder view. From VS you probably did File > Open > Folder. From here, you need to actually open the solution. Double click on the .sln file within the Solution Explorer of VS. That will open up the solution and load the projects, and do the proper nesting of your code behind and designer files.

Next time, you can just open the solution file directly from Windows File Explorer or in VS via File > Open > Project/Solution, then you won't have to waste time in folder view.